# Generate PDF thumbnails in .NET without full Acrobat installed

Tags: .net, pdf, acrobat, adobe-reader

I've seen various methods for generating thumbnails of PDF files in .NET, but unfortunately all of them require full version of Acrobat installed. Is there a way for getting them with free Adobe Reader or any other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find [Ghostscript](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~ghost/doc/GPL/index.htm) to be just great, and it's free! For Windows, it comes as just a simple .dll and .exe, which you can programmatically launch from C#.

Answer (score 2):

You need a PDF to TIFF or JPEG or BMP conversion.  Using a commercial library allow you to many other things with your PDF's.

You could try either of these commercial approaches

http://www.informatik.com/tiff2pdf.html  or 
http://www.quickpdflibrary.com/ or
http://www.expert-tools.com/ENGLISH/index.html or
http://www.amyuni.com/en/developer/pdfcreator/features.html

Answer (score 1):

The only way I know is to load .pdf into readers' hidden ActiveX and then make screenshoots of  reader's control. It look weird (and it is weird) -- but it works.

P.S. Or use third-part components.